# How to create a custom page base on URL for Wordpress?

Tags: urls

How can I achieve the following:

```
example.com/mycategory/my-first-page

example.com/mycategory/a-random-file-name-page
```

If the user enters `http://example.com/mycategory/*`, it will load a standard template page. Inside this page would display a page title depending on the URL e.g. my-first-page will display as "My First Page" with some static contents.

Please advise how should I go about doing that.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic here, so I took the liberty to remove that part from your question.